# Use Javascript to retrieve HTML on same-domain

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Say I have an XML document on a web server ([www.example.com/example.xml](http://www.example.com/example.xml)). On my main page, if I would like to retrieve that document as a string, how can I do this?

I tried `xmlhttprequest` - maybe I'm using it wrong?  It returns it as "undefined."  Help?

```
var xml_page = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml_page.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/example.xml", true);
if (xml_page.readyState == 4 && xml_page.status == 200) {
    var data = xml_page.responseText;
}
document.write(data);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `document.write` fires before the data bas been fetched, to get your code work work *mostly* as-is, it'd have to be a synchronous request, like this:

```
xml_page.open("GET", "http://www.samedomain.com/example.xml", false);
xml_page.send(null);
```

However, it's better to keep it asynchronous (which eliminates `document.write`...also a good thing), like this:

```
xml_page.open("GET", "http://www.samedomain.com/example.xml", true);
xml_page.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xml_page.readyState == 4 && xml_page.status == 200) {
    alert(xml_page.responseText);
  }
};
xml_page.send(null);
```

Comment: @ehfeng: Where Nick's doing `alert(xml_page.responseText);`, you can more usefully do something like `document.getElementById('target').innerHTML + xml_page.responseText;`, which is very close to what you were originally doing. Include a `div` with `id='target'` where you want the XML to appear. (In both cases -- your original and my `innerHTML` above -- you're relying on the browser to handle the XML vs. HTML thing; whether that's really going to be okay will depend on the document and possibly browser...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var xml_page = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml_page.open("GET", "http://www.samedomain.com/example.xml", true);
if (xml_page.readyState == 4 && xml_page.status == 200) {
  var data = xml_page.responseText;
  document.write(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use jQuery.get - it is much simplier and cross-browser.

Comment: This isn't very helpful to the problem at hand - that `data` does not exist until the request is finished.